# How to dimisss UIkeyboard from UItextView on click of a UIbutton

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have a view controller containing `UITextView` and `UIButton`.
i want to dismiss the `UIKeyboard` on click of `UIButton`.I had tried many things but it did not work for me.
I tried these

```
1. [textView endEditing:Yes];
2. [textView resignFirstResponder];
3. [UIApplication sharedApplication] resignFirstResponder];
```

while it working fine on `UITextField`
Please help me Thanks

Comment: may be you are forget to give it's delegate or put your textview's outLat name on resign Method

Comment: put break point on button click method. and check it is calling or not?

Comment: yes its calling ,curser on uitextView hide but keyboard is not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Make an `outlet` of textFeild in .h. In button target method `[txtFeild resignFirstResponder];`
Also try `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: Its not object. Did you mean outlet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. create object of UITextView inside .h file.
2. set the property of that object in .h file.
3. synthesize it in .m file.
4. make IBOutlet and and delegate properly in .xib file.
5. write following in button click method..

   [textviewobject resignFirstResponder];

and also check the click method is properly IBOutlet with the button.